# How to configure network profiles in Centos?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, configuration

I'm trying to setup two network profiles in Centos. One for at home, one for at work.
The home profile has a fixed IP address, fixed gateway and DNS server addresses. The work profile depends on DHCP.

I've created a 'home' and a 'work' directory in /etc/sysconfig/networking/profiles. Each has the following files containing the proper configuration:

```
> -rw-r--r-- 2 root root  422 Apr 17 20:17 hosts
> -rw-r--r-- 5 root root  223 Apr 17 20:18 ifcfg-eth0
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  101 Apr 17 20:17 network
> -rw-r--r-- 2 root root   73 Apr 17 20:18 resolv.conf
```

There was already a 'default' profile, which contains the same files.

Then I issued these commands:

```
system-config-network-cmd --profile work --activate
service network restart
```

I was expecting these files to get copied from the `profiles/work` directory to `/etc/sysconfig/` and `/etc/sysconfig/networking-scripts`. And most files do get copied, except for `ifcfg-eth0`.

Stangely enough that files seems to be overwritten with the current settings when I issue `system-config-network-cmd`. The other files are also touched, but there contents stays in tact.

The system is Centos 5.7 running on a virtual pc within a windows 7 machine. Here is the output for ifconfig:

```
# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:03:FF:6F:2E:AB
          inet addr:192.168.1.200  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::203:ffff:fe6f:2eab/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4199761 errors:7 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1733750 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2316624688 (2.1 GiB)  TX bytes:415533386 (396.2 MiB)
          Interrupt:9
```

Can someone tell what I'm missing here?

Comment: What version of CentOS is this? Are both home/work connections wired/wireless/one of each?

Comment: Centos 5.7 final. Both are wireless connections in reality but the system is running on a virtual machine hosted on windows 7 so the adapter may in fact be mapped to a wired virtual adapter, I'm not sure. I've added ifconfig output to the original post, maybe that helps?

Comment: What VM are you using (vmware, virtual pc etc) and what have you got the virtual adapter set to (bridged, NAT, Host only etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it follows from the RedHat's [documentation](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-network-profiles.html) on networking profiles, you should not use base interface name (`eth0`) for profile interfaces, but have one called as `eth0_work` and so on. BTW, you don't need to restart network configuration, since profile switching handles it by its own. An example:

```
# system-config-network-cmd --profile foobar --activate
Network device deactivating...
Deactivating network device eth0, please wait...
Network device activating...
Activating network device eth0_foobar, please wait...
```

Answer (score 2):

Why use profile here ?

Suppose eth0 was the home line , static IP , edit:

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

```
DEVICE=eth0
IPADDR=192.168.57.200
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
STATIC=yes
ONBOOT=yes
```

And for the other work line , use DHCP ,  edit:

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1`

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
```

And ensure the `network` service starts on boot.

e.g if you run the service at level 2 , 3 , you can do:

`chkconfig --level 23 network on`

Reboot to see changes.